# Edit dhcp configuration file using php script

Tags: php, linux

I want to create a web application to configure DHCP. I want to know how this can be done, as apache user don't have privileges to change files in /etc/ folder of linux.

Any ideas in how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can borrow the privileges to apache user by writing a `setuid` script.
Careful, if done wrong, it could weaken the security of the linux box.

Comment: Let me know if function posix_setuid (Set the UID of the current process) will help